# How to convert lsof hexadecimal IP:port output to decimal notation?

Tags: mac, ip, lsof

I feel dumb for asking but how do I convert this to the IP port combination?

IPV4 0xffffff8015f9aa40

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you might have too much information there, but
`ff ff ff 80` is `255.255.255.128`
`15 f9 aa 40` is `21.249.170.64`

[Here](http://www.kloth.net/services/iplocate.php) is a converter tool for you

Comment: Thanks. I'm on a mac trying to work out what IP(s) Steam connects to while downloading. I'm troubleshooting a problem for a friend. The output I posted is what lsof gives me with: sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"